# Find the last record in MYSQL that corresponds with another field

Tags: mysql

First things first, I am a complete novice at MYSQL although I have some computing knowledge of Pascal based programming which, is probably not all that much help.

I am setting up a data capture system in a factory through Statistical Process Control software that is sending data to our MYSQL database. Among the data that I'm a recording are, the unique number of the machine from where the data is being recorded and the part number being made. These fields are called "machine" and "part" respectively. I need to enter a query in our SPC software that finds the last record for a particular machine in order that I can retrieve part number of the current part being made. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When asking questions here, it is traditional to show what you have tried. It's sort of  like trying to speak French when visiting France even through you know your French is so bad, that you will not prevail.  From the little you offered, I am assuming there is another column (like datetime) that can be used to order the results.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yesterday my knowledge of MYSQL queries was zero hence, no example. Today I know slightly more and I have used this: -
 
SELECT id, date, time, Part_Number
FROM measure_log_turning
WHERE machine = 437
ORDER BY id DESC;
LIMIT 1

It would appear to produce the correct result, although if I try and order by data and time it does not so, I will stick to using id. For a while it wouldn't accept the LIMIT statement but a change in my softwares settings cured that.